# Doing Math Operation using MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

what i try to do is a simple math operation in my project but something works wrong because i get always 0. So my question is:

how can i do this math operations using mvc razor?

what i try is this:

```
@{
  decimal a = 2 / 4;  //--> result 0,5
  int b = a * 100   //--> 50
}
```

the problem is that the first result of the variable a give me 0,5 and i need this value in decimal,
but then i wanted to multiplicate it with 100 that gives me the 50 of datatype int.

hmm, but i can´t figured it out how to do that..

can someone give me a hand with this pls??

Comment: Firstly, this has *nothing* to do with ASP.NET MVC or Razor. It's always worth trying to isolate what's relevant... you'd get the same result in a console app. But basically, the problem is that both 2 and 4 are integer literals, so you're performing *integer* division. Oh, and your code won't compile because `decimal` * `int` is `decimal`, not `int`...

Comment: hmm.. first, thanks for the tip. i keep it in my mind.... but now i have try to change to decimal but nothing happend... can you help me out pls?? im still a newbie :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are performing Integer division which gives you `Zero` here yYou need to convert one of the value into decimal while performing division.

Try This:

```
decimal a = 2.0M / 4;
int b = Convert.ToInt32(a * 100);
```

Comment: yes.. you´re right... its working fine...  i haven´t understand that one value have to decimal to do the math operation... thank you very much.. +1

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
decimal a = 2m / 4m;  //--> result 0,5
int b = (int)(a * 100m);
```